# What is the relationship between convex conjugate and polar set?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Given a [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_system) $\left<X^*,X\right>$ over field $\mathbb R$, and any set $A \subseteq X$, the [polar set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_set) of $A$ is defined as \begin{align}A^\circ = \{x^* \in X^* | \left<x^*,x\right> \leq 1\}.\end{align}

The is a famous bi-polar theorem saying that if $0 \in A$, then the bi-polar set $A^{\circ\circ}$, which is the polar set of the polar set, of a set $A$ is the **closed convex hull** of $A$ under weak-topology.

For a function $f: X \to \mathbb R$, its eipigraph is defined as the set of points above its graph: \begin{align}\mathrm{epi}(f) = \{(x,y) \in X \times \mathbb R | y \geq f(x)\}, \end{align}
and its convex conjugate is defined as a function $f^*: X^* \to \mathbb R$, which satisfies\begin{align}
f^*(x^*) = \sup_{x \in X}\left<x^*, x\right> - f(x).
\end{align}
There is a famous Fenchel-Moreau theorem saying that the bi-conjugate $f^{**}$ of a function $f$ is its lower semi-continous (lsc) convex hull (the largest lsc convex function that is smaller than $f$). A function is lsc iff its epigraph is a closed set in $X \times \mathbb R$, and a function is convex iff its epigraph is a convex set in $X\times \mathbb  R$. Which means, taking bi-conjugate of a function $f$ is equavalent to taking the **closed convex hull** of $\mathrm{epi}(f)$.

Notice that, the bi-polar theorem and Fenchel-Moreau theorem both characterise a closed convex hull of a given set. More critically, they encode the same idea: a closed convex set can be (dually) described by the intersection of all half-planes that contains it.

Given this correspondence, my question is do polar sets and convex conjugates have a deeper relationship? There is [a section on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_theorem#Relation_to_the_Fenchel%E2%80%93Moreau_theorem) saying that bipolar theorem can be proved by Fenchel-Moreau theorem. But this statement doesn't seem to hit the essence of this issue. I wonder, for example, if we can do the reverse: can we prove Fenchel-Moreau theorem by bi-polar theorem? Or if we can describe convex conjugate using the language of polar sets?

Comment: yes. check out Hiriart Urruty and Lemarechal book for this.